# Sublime does not show all files and folders in its sidebar

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2.0.2 on OS X (10.8.5). Most of the times, when I work on a project, I open the according folder so that it shows in the sidebar. Until now this has always been working perfectly.

Now I cloned a really big repository with lots and lots of folders and files, deeply nested within each other. To be exact: It's 20894 files within 4326 folders.

When I open the top-most folder of this repository, everything looks normal - but some folders appear as empty folders. Hence it looks like as if there were no files, although there definitely are some, even folders will not be shown.

It looks as if Sublime cuts everything below a certain folder and refuses to show it.

Does anybody know what causes this behavior and how to fix it?

Just waiting doesn't help: Although it may be that Sublime works in the background to read the tree, even after two hours of waiting nothing happened to the not-shown files and folders. So apparently there must be another problem.

And, as pointed out in the comments: There is no exclusion pattern.

In Sublime's console it says:

```
scan: /some/folder has been seen before, skipping (using inode)
previous path: /some/other/folder inode: 27425614.
```

The folder `/some/folder` is missing. It *may* be that this is correlated, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

*Please note that this question is actually not related to programming itself, but to a tool commonly used by software developers (there's even a tag for it). As the FAQ states that question related to such tools are fine, I posted it here.*

Comment: Do you have any exclude patterns in your sublime settings or in the default sublime settings file?

Comment: No, I don't… though of this as well, but unfortunately that's not the solution :-(. Anyway, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Expect what I mentioned within my question it doesn't say anything.

Comment: It's 2020 and I still ecounter this bug with Linux build 3211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, this is a well-known bug in Sublime Text, which ( at the moment) is still there in version 3. See [this link](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/89047-symlinked-folders-arent-displayed-properly-in-the-sidebar/) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken. If you could have provided a short (2, 3 liner) description to the associated link, that would have helped or maybe would have guided us to look/search in that particular direction. Hope you understand. Thanks and Cheers :-)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is busy trying to read the tree. You may try refresh the project anyway, but reading the large tree does take time.

I met this when I import the Android source tree. I ended up adding excludes to project (blacklisting) or create a smaller project (whitelisting).

**EDIT: (ST3 only)**

<strike>Now that symlinks seems to be the problem</strike> (see **UPDATE** below), you may try adding `follow_symlinks` to your project file (ST3's created project has this as default):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "~/android/frameworks/av/camera"
        },
        {
            "name": "android.media",
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "~/android/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/"
        },
        {
            "name": "android.media/jni",
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "~/android/frameworks/base/media/jni"
        },
        {
            "name": "av/media",
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "~/android/frameworks/av/media",
            "folder_include_patterns": [
                "*media*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "~/android/frameworks/av/services",
            "folder_include_patterns": [
                "*camera*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE (20131106):**

I encounter the same issue working on the AOSP source tree which has no symlinks.
If I used *this* instead of the `andoird.media` and `andoird.media/jni` above, `media/java` will not expand. So the above is a work around by explicitly expanding the folders in the project file.

```
        {
            "name": "android.media (failing)",
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "~/android/frameworks/base/media/",
            "folder_include_patterns": [
                "java",
                "jni"
            ]
        },
```

To create a project `subl <folder>` as usual. Save the project ("Project" -> "Save Project As"), then you can "Project" -> "Edit Project" to fine tune project settings.

To open a project:

- `subl <project>.sublime-project`
- "Project" -> "Open Project"
- "Project" -> "Open Recent"

[Official Documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html)

Comment: Okay, understood. What does "take time" mean? It's clear that you can not give me an exact answer as this depends on the individual folder, but are we talking seconds, minutes, hours, …?

Comment: I would guess around 10-15 minutes. I actually see files popping up in the originally empty folders.

Comment: Hm, okay … I waited for around 2 hours, but it didn't help. No files appeared :-((

Comment: Hmm..sorry then. It seems my experience is different from your case. Is there anything special in the log (cmd+`)?

Comment: That was a good hint. In the console it says `scan: /some/folder has been seen before, skipping (using inode) previous path: /some/other/folder inode: 27425614`. The folder `/some/folder` is missing. Any idea what this means?

Comment: It is smart enough to detect the folder (represented in *nix as `inode`) has not been changed to skip processing it. I was expecting some error logs. Is the folder in your local disk or over remote network?

Comment: Can you do a `time find . -type f > /dev/null` in your project root to see how long it takes, and a `find . -type f | wc -l` to see how many files are there? BTW, I suggest reporting this issue to the [Sublime forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=feb0584f7017c39cb30173363a85f5b3).

Comment: The results: `real: 0m0.898s, user: 0m0.026s, sys: 0m0.157s`. Regarding the numbers: It's 20894 files within 4326 folders.

Comment: Although you didn't *exactly* solve the problem, you helped me a lot and pointed me into the right direction. As nobody else has answered so far, and I really appreciate what you did, I rewarded the bounty to you. Hope you like it :-)

Comment: `follow_symlinks` option come to my mind, please check the edit.

Comment: Which paths do I have to add there?

Comment: I guess you are using `subl <folder>` in console to open the folder. I  usually save the project ("Project" -> "Save Project As"), then you can "Project" -> "Edit Project" to fine tune project settings. `follow_symlinks` seems to be a [ST3 option](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html).

Comment: @GoloRoden, I was hit by the same issue and posted a work around. See if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with folders displaying incorrectly.

What worked for me was deleting the .sublime-workspace file and then open the project again.

Comment: It will be in the same project folder. For example if you created a project called "Website-Fitzy" there will be two files called "Website-Fitzy.sublime-project" and "Website-Fitzy.sublime-workspace" in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

project settings:

```
"follow_symlinks": false,
```

this removes your symlinks from the directory view but all target folders will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if there is a symbolic link to that directory in another directory which is included in the project.

This happened to my on a django project, where the .egg-info contained symbolic links to the templates and static directories.

I simply added ***.egg-info** to **folder_exclude_patterns**:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS",
"node_modules", "__pycache__", "*.egg-info"],
```